# How to calculate total number

Tags: javascript

example I've array

```
 const b =  [ 1000, 2000]
```

Here is my Main number
     `const a = 1500`;

I want to do something like this in for loop

```
 const data1 =  a - b[0]  ( 500 )
 const data2 = data1 - b[1] (-1500)
```

Here is my for loop data

```js
const b =  [ 1000, 2000]
let a = 1500;
for(let i in b) {
   const bData = b[i];
   const data =  a - bData;
   console.log(data)
   // in first loop my output = 500
   // second loop my output = -500 [ Which is wrong ]
}
```

Comment: first of all don't use `const` for the variable in loop which is keep changing. `var` is what you are looking for .

Comment: @AtulKumar `const` just prevents reassignment. `var` has very different semantics.

Comment: You should not use `for .. in` for looping over array [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: @AtulKumar you mean use `let`. There is almost no reason to use `var` if you're allowed to use `let` and if you can use `const`, then `let` is on the table, too. I certainly can't think of any reasons, although I suppose there might be.

Comment: thanks to all comment and very good advice now I change my code and use foreach everything work fine thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce function. So pass the initial value that is `a` as the accumulator. Here `curr` will the each element from the array `b`

```js
const b = [1000, 2000]
const a = 1500;

let fValue = b.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  return acc - curr;

}, a)
console.log(fValue)
```